# How to convert InputText to Text Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a quiz system where i have to take the input from the user in the text field and show in the Text Widget. I am trying to take the input in the text field but after that how to to style it in the Text Widget to show like in image

```
      return Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        ),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                // border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Type a Question...",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
);
```

And how to create the options like when i click on add the option it will show a above option field which i can type the options and then is also converted to the text widget

```
        GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (!hasSolved) {
          setState(() {
            hasSolved = true;
            solvedOption = 2;
          });
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 65,
          right: 65,
          bottom: 15,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: hasSolved && solvedOption == 2
                              ? Colors.white
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: hasSolved && solvedOption == 2
                            ? Icon(
                                Icons.check,
                                size: 15,
                                color: Color(0xffFFC700),
                              )
                            : SizedBox(
                                width: 15,
                                height: 15,
                              ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Maybe?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            if (hasSolved)
              Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 50,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(100),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(100),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "44%",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `Stack` widget along with `TextInputField` & `Text` widget. At a time, only one of `TextInputField` or `Text` will be visible.

[image: The output]

Whatever use enters in `TextInputField`, will be shown in the `Text` widget.

The variables to be used:

```
bool typing = false;
final controller = TextEditingController();
```

The Widget:

```
Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                onTap: startTyping,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Visibility(
                    visible: !typing,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Text(controller.text.isEmpty ? 'Type a question' : controller.text, 
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

The `startTyping` method:

```
void startTyping() {
    setState(() {
      typing = true;
    });

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            setState(() {
              typing = false;
            });
            return Future.value(true);
          },
          child: AlertDialog(
            insetPadding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 24),
            content: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                setState(() {
                  typing = false;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Wrap(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Type a question',
                        hintStyle: bold30Hint,
                      ),
                      controller: controller,
                      autofocus: true,
                      maxLines: 10,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: i have created the button but i am again stucking with the button text to convert it to the text

Comment: You can achieve this again by doing the same. Create a `TextField` for input & when the user submits it, display `OutlineButton` with the input text.

Comment: But i have to write directly into the Button not to again show the dialogBox

Comment: Yes, I understood, but you can't write to a button. You have to use `TextField` for taking input & then display this input to the `OutlineButton` text.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question, this is what my understanding.

1. You want to add the answer options dynamically just by adding the text in TextField widget and by tapping the + button, it has to add in the form of a list items as shown in the image right?
2. Whatever the text you entered and tapping on + button it should create a text tile as per your requirement?

If the above points are correct, then the solution is simple.

Solution:

1. Create an empty List `List<String> inputs = new List<String>();`
2. Then add the text from TextField `OnChanged Parameter` to the above list.
3. Finally create ListView.builder to display the list of options as you need.

Check the official link from Flutter team on displaying the list items. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists

In the above link, they created an example of generating numbers using List.generate. All you have to do is to replace that with your List of inputs data getting from TextField widget. Hope it helps, if not let me know.

Comment: And how to achieve the text field of entering the question after writing the question it can be converted to the TextWidget

Comment: Entering the question and adding the answer options both are different TextWidget's right? @ReemaBalmiki